# PHP XOR encryption fails

Tags: php, xor

i have tried multiple solutions for making an XOR encoding on an uploaded file work, but it always fails. the problem is basically, that the unencrypted file uploads fine to the mysql database:

```
$fp      = fopen($tempPath, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tempPath));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

$encrypted = "";
$key = "123456";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen ($content); $i++)
{
    $encrypted = $encrypted . chr( ord( $content[$i] ) );
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                            doc_files (
                            id, 
                            filedata, 
                            filename, 
                            cryptdata,
                            beschreibung,
                            category,
                            filetype) 
                        VALUES (
                            '$new_guid', 
                            '$encrypted',
                            '$title',
                            '$key',
                            null,
                            '$cat',
                            '$filetype'
                        );";
```

but when changing only the line encoding the file (adding the XOR), the whole script fails with a mysql error. The mysql field format is longblob.

```
$encrypted .= chr( ord( $content[$i] ) ^ ord( $key[$i % strlen ($key)] ) );
```

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '??ѿG?a????og??3O????o3y q:??eH}?????.,Y?Z>?m?]?Y%?|{?$?'
>   at line 12"

thanks for any help in advance

EDIT: adding

```
$encrypted = addslashes($encrypted);
```

makes the code work. The file is uploaded into the database, but has grown in size and is therefore not decodable.

Comment: The notation of XOR in PHP is `xor`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Raptor `^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.operators.bitwise.php); you are referring to the logical XOR operator.

Comment: String concatenation in PHP is done with a dot symbol `.`, not with a plus symbol `+`, so the concatenating assignment operator is `.=`, not `+=`. Also, if security is of importance, instead of creating your own encryption method, it's probably wiser to look into professional grade encryption extensions for PHP, such as [OpenSSL](https://secure.php.net/manual/book.openssl.php).

Comment: as for the operator i tried both and i believe the reference article is specifying both can be used. for the operator, yes that was just a typing issue when reverting to a previous version of my code. anyways it is not producing any file in my database... i appreciate the inputs though

Comment: i have looked through a lot of solutions but they mostly don't seem to work with mysql or fail when handling data from a file uploader. since this should be comparing bytes i guess its a logical operator

Comment: Do you have PHP configured to report/display errors to you in your development environment (please research this, if you don't know what I'm talking about)? If so, what errors does it display? Also, where does the script fail? And does `var_dump( $encrypted );` yield the expected output, if you put that after the `for` loop. Lastly, you are not showing us any database interaction in your code, this makes it hard to determine what other things might be causing your script to fail.

Comment: vardump gives me the lots of data (supposingly encrypted). this is the php error.. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??ѿG?a????og??3O????o3y
q:??eH}?????.,Y?Z>?m?]?Y%?|{?$?' at line 12", so i guess the format is wrong... thanks for the hint so far...

Comment: any idea why it would accept the variable when using it without the ^ operator and suddenly doesnt when i do so?

Comment: when using xor by the way it goes through, but produces just a chain of 0/0/0/....

Comment: was able to fix it by using prepared statements. all working fine now thanks

Answer (score 0):

was able to fix everything by using prepared statements. the addslashes function messed with the encrypted file.